# Why is my discord bot only executing my command one time and one time only?

Tags: python, command, bots, disconnect, discord

I'm in the process of finishing a simple sound clip Discord bot I made by recycling a basic music bot example in python. All I want the bot to do is enter the voice channel of the user who called the command (!womble), play a random sound clip from a folder of sound clips, then leave the voice channel.

"Simple, right?" Of course it isn't, not with this API apparently.

After a BUNCH of trial and error, looking to at least 3 API revisions I got the bot to actually perform the command.....one time. Any further prompts of the command are met with crickets. I can do a !summon and it bring the bot into the channel, but the !womble command no longer works.

````
def bot_leave(self, ctx):
    state = self.get_voice_state(ctx.message.server)
    coro = state.voice.disconnect()
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, state.voice.loop)
    try:
        fut.result()
    except:
        # an error happened sending the message
        pass

@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
async def womble(self, ctx):
    state = self.get_voice_state(ctx.message.server)
    opts = {
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'quiet': True,
    }

    if state.voice is None:
        success = await ctx.invoke(self.summon)
        if not success:
            return

    try:
        random_clip = clip_dir + "\\" + random.choice(os.listdir(clip_dir))
        player = state.voice.create_ffmpeg_player(random_clip, after=lambda: self.bot_leave(ctx))
        player.start()
    except Exception as e:
        fmt = 'An error occurred while processing this request: ```py\n{}: {}\n```'
        await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, fmt.format(type(e).__name__, e))
````

I have tried going into the python chat is the Discord API server, but much like my bot, I'm met with crickets. (Guess that's what I get trying to seek support from a chat that already has 4 conversations going.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you might not need help anymore but just in case you should try removing the coroutine.result() and run it directly. I.e change:

```
def bot_leave(self, ctx):
state = self.get_voice_state(ctx.message.server)
coro = state.voice.disconnect()
fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, state.voice.loop)
try:
    fut.result()
except:
    # an error happened sending the message
    pass
```

to:

```
def bot_leave(self, ctx):
state = self.get_voice_state(ctx.message.server)
coro = state.voice.disconnect()
try:
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, state.voice.loop)
except:
    # an error happened sending the message
    pass
```

That's the only thing I could think of seeing your code snippet, but the problem may lie elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Welp, that managed to improve the bot in one aspect: the bot will now rejoin the server. First time works flawlessly, the second time, the bot shows up....and just sits there.

It doesn't seem to like creating the player more than one time....or at least that's what I'm assuming.